# Copy Javascript object array value

Tags: javascript, arrays

from a dropdown I'm selecting an array from a javascript object:

```
$("#selector").change(function() {
    let array = [];
    Object.values(group[$("#selector").val()]).forEach(x => array.push(x));
    console.log(`Group: ${$("#selector").val()}, Array: ${array}`);
});
```

against an array such as:

```
let group = {
LocationA: [
{
        name: "A",
        length: 11,
        width: 9,
        height: 9
    },
    {
        name: "B",
        length: 26,
        width: 6,
        height: 20
    },
    {
        name: "C",
        length: 16,
        width: 12,
        height: 14
    }
],
locationB: [{
        name: "S-10662",
        length: 32,
        width: 18,
        height: 12
    }...
```

But the array outputs as a list of ***[object Object]***, not an array.  I'm having difficulty copying a value (which is an array) into an array.  I've searched for such an example, I cannot find one here.

Comment: added solution @jim-from-princeton

Comment: The main problem that you are experiencing is confusing an `array` with an `object`. Below is a good working solution, but I would recommend reading up on the difference to help you in the future. https://medium.com/@zac_heisey/objects-vs-arrays-42601ff79421

Answer (score 1):

Change this line to :

```
console.log(`Group: ${$("#selector").val()}  Array: `, samplearray);
```

Variable you can console like this for printing array can't concatenate.

```js
let group = {
  LocationA: [{
      name: "A",
      length: 11,
      width: 9,
      height: 9
    },
    {
      name: "B",
      length: 26,
      width: 6,
      height: 20
    },
    {
      name: "C",
      length: 16,
      width: 12,
      height: 14
    }
  ],
  locationB: [{
    name: "S-10662",
    length: 32,
    width: 18,
    height: 12
  }]
};
$("#selector").change(function() {
  let samplearray = [];
  Object.values(group[$("#selector").val()]).forEach(x => samplearray.push(x));
  console.log(`Group: ${$("#selector").val()}  Array: `, samplearray);
  console.log(samplearray);
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="selector">
<option value="locationB" >locationB</option>
<option value="LocationA" >LocationA</option>
</select>
</body>
```

Comment: excellent, thanks.  I was struggling with that for some time!!

Comment: Don’t forget to upvote and accept if you feel this help you. You have enough reputation do the same

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the forEach because you're already extracting the values as an array with Object.values; you can directly store it to your array variable:

```
    let array = Object.values(group[$("#selector").val()]);
```

That gives you an array of objects; with the forEach you were telling javascript to iterate through each of those objects, which isn't possible.
If the goal was to also extract the values of those objects, then you could do:

```
$("#selector").change(()  => {
    let array = Object.values(group[$("#selector").val()]);
    console.log(array)
    let expandedArray = [];
    array.forEach(object => {
        expandedArray = [...Object.values(object), ...expandedArray]
    });
    console.log(expandedArray)
});
```

Comment: You are right not required `forEach` because its already there. Upvoting this because you have right point.